# Responsive Square in CSS

Tags: css, responsive, aspect-ratio, css-grid

Does [CSS grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) have any way to make item height match item width, ensuring items are square ?

e.g. Can we make the width and height *both* be "25% of grid container width"?

Comment: AFAIK, no. `:(`

Comment: There's some irony if grid layout can't make a responsive version of the structure commonly referred to as a grid.

Comment: Ha ha... Agreed with you mate! `:)`

Comment: AFAIK, yes  `;-) `

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ezzsgkgg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Of course you can !*

**CSS**:

```
.wrapper{ display: grid;  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);}
.wrapper > div { border: 1px solid black;position:relative;}
.wrapper > div:before {display: table; padding-top: 100%; content: '';}
.content{position: absolute;top:0; left:0; width:100%;height:100%;display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div><div class="content">1</div></div>
  <div><div class="content">2</div></div>
  <div><div class="content">3</div></div>
  <div><div class="content">4</div></div>
</div>
```

**Exemple in production** : http://www.montblancnaturalresort.com

**Snippet**:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>div:before {
  display: table;
  padding-top: 100%;
  content: '';
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="content">1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="content">2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="content">3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="content">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really cool --- I've used it in a piece of code and I can see it working for me. Thanks! I have a request though --- could you please explain how the pseudo-element works to style the content? Why does its presence and the `display:table; padding-top:100%;` work to keep the height/width in sync?

Answer (score 3):

Though this has been answered. But there have been multiple updates in CSS since this question has been asked. With new properties making a square is too easy.
Using `aspect-ratio` property, you can build responsive shapes in Rectangles, Circles, Squares or more.

```css
:root {
  --square: 800px;
  --background: teal;
}
.square {
    background: var(--background);
    width: 100%;
    max-width: var(--square);
    height: auto;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```